# How do I make a vertical graph based on inputs?

Tags: c

Input

```
1 1 3 1
```

Output

```
  # 
  # 
####
```

Input

```
0 3 0 4 5
```

Output

```
    #
   ##
 # ##
 # ##
 # ##
```

This is the code I have so far..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    int height[80],length=0,max=0;
    while ((scanf("%d",&height[length++])) != EOF && length <=79) {
        if (height[length-1] > max) {
            max=height[length-1];
        }
    }
}
```

The input may not contain no more than 80 values.
I am not entire certain on how to add on more codes from here.

Comment: It might help to draw out on graph paper how you would print that graph one line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(void) {
    int st[MAX];
    int n = 0;
    int i, j;
    int max_value = -1;

    while (scanf("%d", st + n) != EOF) {
        if (st[n] > max_value)
            max_value = st[n];
        ++n;
    }

    for (i = max_value; i > 0; --i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (st[j] >= i)
                printf("#");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Input

`0 3 0 4 5 "Enter" "Ctrl+D"`

### Output

```
    #
   ##
 # ##
 # ##
 # ##
```

Comment: Thank you! but is there a way to keep this program running until reaching EOF? like for instance, I input, get output, input get output ...on and on? until EOF?

Comment: @stanleycho you can take each line input as a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) until you reach EOF. Then within the loop take the inputs for the array from the string.

Comment: @YunbinLiu no worries I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
length -= 1;
for(;max>=0;--max){
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        putchar(height[i] > max ? '#' : ' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

---

Also `while ((scanf("%d",&height[length++])) != EOF && length <=79){` is wrong.
This is because the while-body will not be executed after `height[79]` is read.
So, for example, modify it as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DATA_MAX_LEN 80

int main (void){
    int height[DATA_MAX_LEN], length = 0, max = 0;
    for(int len = 0, h; len < DATA_MAX_LEN && scanf("%d", &h) == 1; ++len){
        height[length++] = h;
        if (height[length-1] > max){
            max=height[length-1];
        }
    }
    while(max--){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
            putchar(height[i] > max ? '#' : ' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the maximum height of all the inputs stored in `arr[]`. Now have an outer loop that iterates `j` from maximum height `hm` till 1. Every iteration of outer loop, go through all values of inner loop and check if `arr[i] >= j`. If yes, print a `#` else print a space.

```
int arr[80];
int n;

cin>>n;

int hm = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
    hm = max(hm, arr[i]);
}

for(int i = hm; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
        if(arr[j]>=i)
            cout<<"#";
        else cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written this code based on the code in the question. This will get input number one by one. It can only consume up to 80 numbers.

```
void draw(const int* height, int length, int max)
{
    char* t_mat;
    char* mat;

    size_t mat_size = length * max * sizeof(char);

    t_mat = (char*)malloc(mat_size);
    mat = (char*)malloc(mat_size);

    // build transposed graph
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int value = height[i];

        for (int j = max - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j + value >= max)
                t_mat[i * max + j] = '#';
            else
                t_mat[i * max + j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    // tanspose t_mat to mat
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            mat[i * length + j] = t_mat[j * max + i];

    // print
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            printf("%c", mat[i * length + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(t_mat);
    free(mat);
}

int main()
{
    int height[80], length=0, max=0;

    while (length < 80 && scanf("%d",&height[length++]) != EOF) {

        // update max number
        if (height[length-1] > max)
            max=height[length-1];

        // draw the graph with the updated number
        draw(height, length, max);
    }
}
```

This method first creates a *[transposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)* version of the input. For example, if your input sequence is:

```
5 3 0 4 5
```

this code first creates a `char` matrix that corresponds to:

```
#####  // 5 #'s in this row
  ###  // 3 #'s in this row
       // 0 #'s in this row
 ####  // 4 #'s in this row
#####  // 5 #'s in this row
```

and then transpose it to get the desired graph:

```
#   #
#  ##
## ##
## ##
## ##
```

If you compile it and run it with this input sequence: `5 3 0 4 5` you'll get following sequence of output.

```
5 // <- your input
#
#
#
#
#
3 // <- your input
#
#
##
##
##
0 // <- your input
#
#
##
##
##
4 // <- your input
#
#  #
## #
## #
## #
5 // <- your input
#   #
#  ##
## ##
## ##
## ##
```

This program will terminate after consuming 80 input numbers.